# Sum of digits in random generated arrays

Tags: java, math

I know this may stand for a silly question but I have got a lot of problems with this.
I will first explain how it should work  :
1)Generate random Array with size in range <4,7>
2)Fill it with random elements in range <100, 999>
3)Print the index of three numbers with biggest digit sum
So the question is-how? I know I should implement this:

```
             SumOfDigits += ElementFromArray % 10;
              ElementFromArray /= 10;
```

But i have got no idea where. I tried to add this as a `if (i>0)` loop inside `for` loop-but its not working.
Also how at the end im going to print the proper elements? Should I use `Arrays.sort(tab)` and then `System.out.println(tab[tab.length - 1])` (and so on with -2, -3 for 3 last elements)?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Ex1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int size = rand.nextInt(4) + 4;

        int tab[] = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            int elements = rand.nextInt(900) + 100;
            tab[i] = elements;

        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tab));
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you coded points 1 and 2.  So, for point 3, sort the array in descending order and print the first 3 elements.  Alternatively, find the largest element in the array, print it, find the second largest element, and so on.

Comment: Are you limited to arrays or can you use Collection types like Map, List etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use while loop: here is a quick and dirty solution:

```
private static void main10(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int size = rand.nextInt(4) + 4;

    int[] tab = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        int element = rand.nextInt(900) + 100;
        tab[i] = element;

    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tab));
    // calculate digits:
    int[] digitsums = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        int element = tab[i];
        int sumOfDigits = 0;
        while (element > 0) {
            sumOfDigits += element % 10;
            element /= 10;
        }
        digitsums[i] = sumOfDigits;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digitsums));
    int[] copyOfdigitsums = Arrays.copyOf(digitsums, digitsums.length);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        int j = getIndexOfLargest(copyOfdigitsums);
        System.out.println("index of " + i + "largest is " + j + ", with a digitsum of " + copyOfdigitsums[j]);
        copyOfdigitsums[j] = 0;
    }
}

static int getIndexOfLargest(int[] digitsums) {
    int largest = 0;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < digitsums.length; i++) {
        int d = digitsums[i];
        if (largest < d) {
            largest = d;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If we aim for a solution using only arrays I would use a 2d array to hold the sum of digits and the index of the corresponding number in the `tab` array

So first create the array based on the size of the original array

```
int[][] sums = new int[size][2];
```

then in the for loop, calculate the sum of the random number and store it and the index

```
sums[i][0] = elements / 100 + (elements / 10) % 10 + elements % 10;
sums[i][1] = i;
```

Then sort the `sums` array using a custom comparator

```
Arrays.sort(sums, new Comparator<int[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o2[0], o1[0]);
    }
});
```

And finally print the index and number of the numbers of the top 3

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d: %d\n", sums[i][1], tab[sums[i][1]]);
}
```